# AUTO_INCREMENT in two places

Tags: php, mysql, sql, auto-increment

I came across following sql statements and you can see that AUTO_INCREMENT is in two different places. Can you explain the different, I know the first one is auto incrementing id. But what does the second one mean?

```
CREATE TABLE `categories`(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
     `image_path` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Second statement.

```
CREATE TABLE `categories`(
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
     `image_path` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

I referenced http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html. But I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the second statement sets the first number to be used in the id at 4.

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Sets the column name and tells the DB to auto increment the number when a new row is added.

```
) ENGINE = InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Sets the Engine used for the table, the charset and that it should start numbering at 4, not 1.

[`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) explains this in a bit more detail.

> - AUTO_INCREMENT
>
> The initial AUTO_INCREMENT value for the table. In MySQL 5.0, this
>   works for MyISAM and MEMORY tables. It is also supported for InnoDB as
>   of MySQL 5.0.3.

Comment: So, in second statement id is auto_incrementing. If there is another int variable, will it increment too?

Comment: You can only have one auto_increment column a table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html  " Note
There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT column per table, it must be indexed, and it cannot have a DEFAULT value."